# checkboxlist column gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have gridview I have column that should be checkboxlist like dropdownlist column but how can I let the list appear when click in the column ?I don't want the list to appear unless the user want to check some items

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Turn the column into a templated column.  Make a panel with the checkboxlist in it.  Set the display style to 'none' for the panel.  On the hover over event of that cell, set the display style of the panel to ‘’.